# Css mobile not center

Tags: css

When I see my website through the computer, everything is very centralized, the way I want it, but when I go to the cell phone, all the items go to the left and it gets really ugly, I don't know what's going on

```css
.shop-card {
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif;
}
.shop-card .title {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #23211f;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.shop-card .desc {
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  color: #23211f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="shop">
    

   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@Giveaway">
            <strong>  @Gi...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="With this role, you can participate on giveaways!"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>   With this role, you can participate on giveaways!... 
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:   #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('1','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@Moderators">
            <strong>  @Mode...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="Be moderator for 1 day"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>   Be moderator for 1 day... 
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:   #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('2','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@Administrator">
            <strong>  @Admi...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="Be ADMIN for 1 day"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>   Be ADMIN for 1 day... 
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:   #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('3','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@Premium">
            <strong>  @Prem...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="BE A VIP"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>  BE A VIP
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:#dabe72" class="fas fa-money-bill"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('4','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@Support">
            <strong>  @Supp...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="SUPPORT US"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>  SUPPORT US
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:   #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('5','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@new role">
            <strong>  @new ...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="SUPPORT US"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>  SUPPORT US
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:   #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('6','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@DISBOARD.org">
            <strong>  @DISB...</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="DISBOARD"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>  DISBOARD
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 1.0k <i style="color:#dabe72" class="fas fa-money-bill"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 0</strong> <strong style="color:"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('7','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
   <div style="margin-right:15px;" class="shop-card">
      <div style="background-color:#7386d5" class="product">
         <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="color:white;font-size:30px;padding:20px" data-original-title="@-">
            <strong> @-</strong>
         </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top:10px">
         <hr>
         <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" style="height:50px" class="desc" data-original-title="BUY IT FOR OWNER"><i style="font-size:20px" class="far fa-file-alt"></i>   BUY IT FOR OWNER... 
         </div>
         <hr>
         <div class="cta">
            <div style="text-align:center" class="price">Price: 10.0k <i style="color:  #7289da" class="fas fa-gem"></i></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <strong style="color:black">Level: 1000</strong> <strong style="color:#da7272"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></strong>
            </div>
            <br>
             <button class="button_div" style="color:white;" onclick="buyrank('8','689937289282846776')">Redeem</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   
    </div>
```

[image: pc view]

[image: mobile view]

basically, everything is centralized on the mobile, except the items. For reference, just look at the "load more" button in the 2 cases, as it is centralized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the id "shop", add the css `text-align:center` and remove the `margin-right:15px` in the `.shop-card` in the mobile screen

```
#shop{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: yeah, it's centralized. But its an unnecessary CSS